# Primary key on dynamic model

Tags: python, django, django-models, primary-key

I'm building an app with dynamic models (following guidelines on [1]) to create an interface for an already existing database.

This is my function to create one of the models (in fact it has more fields and stuff, but this should be enough):

```
def create_model(name):
    # Meta class
    class Meta:
        pass

    # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
    attrs = {'__module__': 'mymodule',
             'Meta': Meta,
             'fields': {
                'myID': models.CharField(max_length=2, db_column='myID', primary_key=True),
                '__unicode__': lambda self: self.myID,
                }
            }

    # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
    model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

    admin.site.register(model, admin.ModelAdmin)

    return model
```

But when I try to access this model I get the following `OperationalError`:

```
(1054, "Unknown column 'database_table.id' in 'field list'")
```

It seems that Django is not taking into account my `prymary_key` definition for field `myID` and it's creating the default `id` field.

Am I missing something? Is it a ''bug'' related to dynamic model creation? Anyone knows a workaround for this? Thanks

[1] https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields and methods shouldn't be within the `'fields'` dictionary in your `attrs`, but should be at the top-level of the `attrs` dict.

This:

```
attrs = {'__module__': 'mymodule',
         'Meta': Meta,
         'fields': {
            'myID': models.CharField(max_length=2, db_column='myID', primary_key=True),
            '__unicode__': lambda self: self.myID,
            }
        }
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        pass

    fields = { 
       'myID': models.CharField(max_length=2, db_column='myID', primary_key=True),
       '__unicode__': lambda self: self.myID,
      }

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.myID
```

The `ModelBase` metaclass takes any field (actually any object with a `contribute_to_class` method) that's defined on the top-level of the class, and uses the `contribute_to_class` method on the field to 'add' it to the actual class. In this process, the field gets added to the `fields` dictionary, but you shouldn't  define the fields dictionary before the actual metaclass is run. Your `attrs` should look like this instead:

```
attrs = {'__module__': 'mymodule',
         'Meta': Meta,
         'myID': models.CharField(max_length=2, db_column='myID', primary_key=True),
         '__unicode__': lambda self: self.myID,
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! After reading your answer I came back to my reference (see [1] above) to check if it was mistaken, and I have just realized it makes exactly what you say: `attrs.update(fields)` I implemented it the wrong way...

Answer (score 2):

*I'm building an app with dynamic models (following guidelines on [1]) to create an interface for an already existing database.*

Are you sure this is the correct approach? Don't you want to use `manage.py inspectdb` to create models from that database instead? See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: I didn't know about `inspectdb` command (facepalm). It would have been a really useful starting point, but now it's late :/

Anyway, I like the dynamic approach because I have many models with names and fields based on language ids (EngVariant, SpaVariant,...) and this way I keep closer to DRY principle.